# Xmpp connection using asmack and bonjour on android

Tags: android, bonjour, smack, asmack

I'm trying to do a server-less app for IM. I use apple bonjour protocol to discover xmpp services. But once I get those I can't connect to my host (linux computer using pidgin + bonjour).

Here is my code (taken from [here](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/Connection.html)) :

```
public class Xmpp extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0)
    {
        ConnectionConfiguration connConfig =
                new ConnectionConfiguration("192.168.0.11", 5298, "bonjour");
        XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);
         try
        {
            // Connect to the server
            connection.connect();
             // Most servers require you to login before performing other tasks.
            connection.login("grea08", "mypass");
            // Start a new conversation with John Doe and send him a message.
            Chat chat = connection.getChatManager().createChat("grea09@192.168.0.11", new MessageListener() {


                 public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
                     // Print out any messages we get back to standard out.
                     Log.v(getClass().getName(), "Received message: " + message);
                 }
             });

            chat.sendMessage("Howdy!");
        } catch (XMPPException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Xmpp error !", e);
        }
         // Disconnect from the server
         connection.disconnect();
        return null;
    }

}
```

I've got an `XmppException` "No response from server". I think that the host is not an XMPP server and we must use the protocol [this](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0174.html) way.

Comment: is it really `192.189...` and not `192.168...`? Most internal IP-addresses are 192.168.something.

Comment: Ah yes a simple mistake, thanks, I'm tring

Comment: Nope that isn't this that cause the "No Response" Error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Smack and aSmack has no support for [XEP-0174](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0174.html)** (aka. link-local or serverless messaging). [Jonas patches](http://community.igniterealtime.org/thread/36186) never made it into the trunk. The corresponding issue to track is [SMACK-262](http://issues.igniterealtime.org/browse/SMACK-262).

Comment: You could try the patch attached to SMACK-262. But it will likely need modification to be successful applied to the current trunk of Smack.

Comment: I need to compile the old one or can I patch the newer version ?
When I've done that I just need to use the "LL" classes ? XMPPLLConnection, LLPacketReader, etc ?
Is there anything I need to know ?

Comment: Sorry, you have to find out yourself. I have no experience with the LL patches for Smack.

Answer (score 1):

[Gibberbot](https://github.com/guardianproject/Gibberbot) open source project supports XMPP **and** Bonjour serverless communication.

It also [can be installed from Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=info.guardianproject.otr.app.im&hl=en).

Perhaps you can check out its sources and extract the relevant code for your app. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try creating your `XMPPConnection` with a configuration:

```
ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("192.189.0.11", port);
//Set optional configurations on the config object.
Connection connection = new XMPPConnection(config);
```

Comment: I just tried, and it works further. Now I get an XMPP error "No Response from server". Maybe I'm doing it wrong as the host is not a xmpp server but another client. Is there a way to send message like described in this page http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0174.html ?